# The return type 'StopWatchWidgetState' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app, and have a button which takes me to a new screen, called StopWatchWidgetState(). I tried it in my main.dart file, and everything works. Now, I am trying to call StopWatchWidgetState() from another screen, and am getting the error described in the title of this post. I do not know why, and any help is appreciated. Here is the button from which I am trying to call StopWatchWidgetState() from:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StopWatchWidgetState()),
      );
    },
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.timer,
      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
    ),
  ),
```

And here is the StopWatchWidgetState() code block itself:

```
class StopWatchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const StopWatchWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<StopWatchWidget> createState() => StopWatchWidgetState();
}

class StopWatchWidgetState extends State<StopWatchWidget> {
  final Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  String stopWatchText = '00:00';
  void startStopWatch() {
    if (_stopwatch.isRunning) {
      _stopwatch.stop();
      // updateScramble();
    } else {
      stopWatchText = '00:00';
      _stopwatch
        ..reset()
        ..start();
    }

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (!_stopwatch.isRunning) {
          timer.cancel();
        }
        stopWatchText =
            '${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(_stopwatch.elapsed.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isPressed = false;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Trainer',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  actions: [
                    Center(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isPressed = !isPressed;
                            if (isPressed) {
                            } else {}
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const TwoTimerAlgsets(),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          '2x2',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text(
                          '3x3',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text(
                          '4x4',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                  title: const Text('Choose Algset:'),
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.add_circle_outline,
              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
            ),
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 60,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ParentWidget(),
            // child: Center(
            //   child: InkWell(
            //     onTap: () {},
            //     child: const Text(
            //       "F R U R' U' F'",
            //       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            //     ),
            //   ),
            // ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 665,
              child: TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                ),
                onPressed: startStopWatch,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 145.0),
                  child: Text(
                    stopWatchText,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your widget is `StopWatchWidget` not `StopWatchWidgetState`